# Delete a node and a menu_link

Tags: nodes, routes

I have a simply question, it's possible to delete a node and at the same time delete a menu_links ? For exemple when i will use the button delete of a node of my entity "PROJECT" i want to delete automaticaly a menu_links created before. I found the HOOK_Delete but how to use this function in a particular entity ? Like the HOOK_form_alter we can choose the form_id, there is a HOOK like this ? :

```
Mymodule_delete($nid) {
    if($entity == "project") {
        delete($nid);
    }
}
```

Maybe can i change the `$form['actions']['delete ??']` in my form alter and use my own function ?

```
_myfunction_delete_project($nid) {
    $query = "Here get the entity of my $nid";

    if($query == "project") {
        delete($nid);
        delete($my menu links);
    }
}
```

I hope you understand my request

Thanks

Comment: No need to write any custom code for this. I think menu link automatically got deleted when you delete any entity.

Comment: Ok, i want to delete a menu link not bonded with my entity, to explain, when i add an entity "Project" i create a special menu link in my menu with "menu_link_save" but when i delete this entity i want to delete the menu_links created before. They are not bonded together.

Comment: Check my answer.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply using [hook_node_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7).

```
function hook_node_delete($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'any_content_type') { // for specific content type
    // here your code use $node->nid
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's what i'm searching ! i didn't know we can check the type of node in $node :)

Comment: Glad it helps... :)